# Is there a way to smoothly tween the position of list items when adding or removing from an AnimatedList?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have an `AnimatedList`, and I can add and remove items just fine. My issue is that when I add an item to the top of the list, the items below it jump down to make space for it, instead of transitioning smoothly.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935586/4571656) which provides a solution to smoothly animating items up when one is removed, but I can't get the same solution to work for inserting items.

This is what I have so far. As the item is added to the top of the list, the elements below it shift smoothly. However, the scale-in transition of the new element also follows this shift.

```
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  Foo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final kDuration = const Duration(seconds: 1);

  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  final _key = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  List<Color> _items;
  int _counter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _items = <Color>[];
    _counter = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Animated List Spike'),
      ),
      body: AnimatedList(
        key: _key,
        initialItemCount: _items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              // This transition creates the smooth shift-down effect.
              SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: animation.drive(Tween(begin: 0, end: 1)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 64,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // This is the content we actually want to show.
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                heightFactor: 0,
                child: SlideTransition(
                  position: Tween(
                    begin: Offset(0, -0.5),
                    end: Offset(0, 0),
                  ).animate(animation),
                  child: ScaleTransition(
                    scale: CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOutBack)
                        .animate(animation),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Card(
                        color: _items[index],
                        child: Container(height: 64),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: addItem,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  void addItem() {
    _items.insert(0, Colors.primaries[_counter++ % Colors.primaries.length]);
    _key.currentState.insertItem(0, duration: widget.kDuration);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to have the elements shift smoothly and *then* have the new element scale in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `Interval` curves. By having one curve end at the `0.5` mark and the other begin there, I was able to make the elements slide down, and then have my new element scale in.

```
CurveTween(
  curve: Interval(
    0.5, // Start halfway through the animation.
    1.0, // Stop at the end of the animation.
    curve: Curves.easeOutBack,
  ),
).animate(animation),
```

Full solution for question:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: animation.drive(
                  CurveTween(
                    curve: Interval(
                      0.0,
                      0.5,
                      curve: Curves.linear,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 64,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                heightFactor: 0,
                child: ScaleTransition(
                  scale: CurveTween(
                    curve: Interval(
                      0.5,
                      1.0,
                      curve: Curves.easeOutBack,
                    ),
                  ).animate(animation),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Card(
                      color: _items[index],
                      child: Container(height: 64),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
```